# Git: How to add a file from older head to current head

Tags: git, github

I am facing one peculiar issue and need your guidance.

I am building one jenkins pipleine which builds the files in one particular branch, let's say BRANCH_A.

But the build is failing since one particular big .war file is missing. It was there in an older revision A, but later it was deleted. So it's not present in current HEAD.

But this file is huge and git is not allowing me add the file in the latest HEAD (Max object size limit is 52,428,800 bytes). But surprisingly this file was added in 2020 in the old revision A! May be that time the restriction was not there from the IT team.

So same branch, BRANCH_A, same file is existing in old HEAD A,but not in current HEAD. How to get that file in the current HEAD without doing the push operation?

Otherwise is it possible to create a symbolic link from current HEAD to the old HEAD so that the build passes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this .war file have to be under version control? If not, I would probably move it outside of git entirely and have the CI job pick it up from an external source

Comment: Thanks @Paolo - makes sense. We have another GIT for storing huge files. I will store it there and refer it from the jenkins script file.